# Multi org deploy in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) tutorial to setup multi org deployment. After creating a card in step 8, I am unable to import the card. I get the following error:
Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-undefined" for connection type "undefined".

I've cross checked the connection profiles but could not find the reason.
Could you please help.

Comment: you are probably using node 6. You need to use node 8. Uninstall Composer, uninstall node 6, install node 8 and then install the composer tools again.

Comment: I am using node 8 only

Comment: ok, what version of composer-cli have you got. ie composer -v will tell you. Are you running 0.16.x but have tried to use hyperledger fabric 1.1 where the version of composer has to be 0.19.x ?

Comment: I am using composer 0.16.x with fabric hlfv1 connection profile. Although I also have fabric 1.1 in this case I am not using that profile

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with the connection profile used to create the card. I would check that the connection profile, see if it defines a property called 'type' with a value of 'hlfv1'. If for example it defines a property called 'x-type' then it isn't a composer 0.16.x profile

Comment: If I do composer -v then it shows v0.16.6. But my connection profile has  "x-type": "hlfv1".

Comment: Composer 0.16.x can only work with fabric 1.0. Composer 0.19.x can only work with fabric 1.1. The connection profile format has changed. x-type is a Composer 0.19.x profile and cannot be used with 0.16.x. The tutorial you are following is for Composer 0.19.x.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @david_k

Comment: Hi @david_k can you please clarify me on  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937260/do-i-need-to-use-fabric-sdk-if-am-using-hyperledger-composer) question too

Comment: The answer below is version specific and I would suggest going with the latest version all the time or else there will be compatibility issues. Please follow the below link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the tutorial you are referring to is for "latest" which is Composer v0.19.  This tutorial directs you to create connection.json files in the v0.19 format.

If you are using Composer v0.16 you need to use a different version of the tutorial to create connection.json and cards of the right format.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org